# Why Java VisualVM is not showing WildFly when it is started as a service?

Tags: java, wildfly, jvisualvm

My PC's operating system is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. 
I am using JDK 7 Update 80.
I am using WildFly 8.2.1.

When I start WildFly as a Console then in Java VisualVM I can see it.

Then I install WildFly as a Service. When I start the service I dont see it in Java VisualVM. How come? The Service s running fine. It is just not being picked by Java VisualVM which is strange. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you running VisualVM as *administrator*? Is your WildFly service set to be run as a particular user?

Comment: @watery I am running VisualVM as administrator. My WildFly service is Log On As `Local System`.

Answer (score 4):

When a Java program runs, it stores the process id somewhere in user-specific storage *(file / registry / memory? Doesn't really matter!)*. When VisualVM starts, it display the list from that storage.

Your service is running as a different user, so VisualVM can't "see" it. VisualVM can still connect to the Java process, if enabled by the service, you just have to do it manually, e.g. enter port number.

Answer (score 2):

The jvisualvm discovers locally running applications by looking at `%TMP%\hsperfdata_username` folder, where `%TMP%` is the temp folder for the Windows user the process is running under.

- For java process running as a service this likely to be at `C:\Windows\Temp`or `C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp` (assuming that temp folder configured in environment variables as TMP =%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp )
- For application running under the normal user, the pid file will be located at `C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_yourUser`

If jvisualvm and the process you about to monitor run not with the same user, the visualVm will not find the application. To solve this problem you can temporarily point TMP environment variable to look at the same temp folder.

To monitor Wildfly application server you will need to run jvisualvm as:

```
C:\> set TMP=c:\Users\wildfly_user\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\> jvisualvm.exe -cp:a c:\wildfly\bin\client\jboss-client.jar
```

More information on jvisualVm troubleshooting is available at https://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html?Java_VisualVM

Comment: what is the user is SYSTEM? where that temp folder is then?

Comment: I guess that's the problem, you can't get access to the temp fomder or system user. Run you WF as a user and then you can connect VisualVm to it